# Remote Storage for Magento 2 CE

Tags: magento2, s3

I have a few questions regarding the remote storage feature of Magento 2

1. Is it available with Magento 2 CE
2. Does it support S3 Compatible storage like b2, minio etc

Do these folders get stored in bucket?

1. var/*
2. pub/media/*
3. pub/static/*
4. etc/*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for these.

1. Is it available with Magento 2 CE - Yes
2. Does it support S3 Compatible storage like b2, minio etc - Yes, it can be used with S3 compatible storage and R2 as well.